# Disable URL Encoding ? [Quarkus]

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, rest-client

I got an URL for querying Prometheus: .../api/v1/query?query=rate(prometheus_http_requests_total[1m]) . But it always return 404 Error and when I debug, the URL changed to this: .../api/v1/query?query=rate%28prometheus_http_requests_total%5B1m%5D%29 .

Please help.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.viettel</groupId>
    <artifactId>evaluating-svc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <failsafe.useModulePath>false</failsafe.useModulePath>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.7.4.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-qute</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j2-jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Prometheus -->
        <!-- The client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hotspot JVM metrics-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
            <version>0.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Exposition HTTPServer-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_httpserver</artifactId>
            <version>0.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Push-gateway exposition-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_pushgateway</artifactId>
            <version>0.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>                                             ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner                                         </native.image.path>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager                                         </java.util.logging.manager>
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

RestClient: My query string is: "rate(prometheus_http_requests_total[1m])"

```
package com.example.client;

import com.example.client.response.PrometheusResponse;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.annotation.RegisterClientHeaders;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.annotation.RegisterProvider;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.jaxrs.QueryParam;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Singleton
@Path("/api/v1/query")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "prometheus-client")
@RegisterClientHeaders(RequestInternalServiceHeaderFactory.class)
@RegisterProvider(RequestInternalServiceFilter.class)
public interface MetricClient {
    @GET
    @Path("query")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    PrometheusResponse getTpsSummary(@QueryParam String query);
}
```

Comment: Don't. Query parameters have to be encoded properly. Instead, fix your server endpoint to properly decode the query. Or better, use [a query language that doesn't need escaping](https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser)

Comment: @Jorn Thanks for your recommendation, I will look forward to it. However I'm not sure if server endpoint recognize encoded query, in this case Prometheus (PromQL).